# C# как нажать на ссылку?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{
    PJS.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://vk.com/settings"); 
    PJS.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="chgaddr"]/div[1]/a")).Click();           
}
```

Всё, и по классам, и по `id` но не нажимается.  используется Selenium WebDriver phantomjs

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какие библиотеки или framework'и вы используете и что пытаетесь сделать. Т.к. по вопросу ничего не понятно и соответственно сложно как-то помочь. Вот вам в помощь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: из кода ясно что .GoToUrl это переход поссылке ,     FindElement  по этому элементу нужно кликнуть ,.Click() это и ежу понятно ,  всё просто как 2+2   но оне почемуто не кликается

Comment: By.XPath  //*[@id="chgaddr"]/div[1]/a  вот этот патч , в коде выше не тот указан , нужно кликнуть по текстовой ссылке Изменить